# LateInitializationError : Field 'titleControl' has not been initialized

Tags: flutter, kotlin-lateinit

I'm new to flutter and I have this error after running someone else project that I clone. The error is this `LateInitializationError : Field 'titleControl' has not been initialized`.

I don't know which code caused the Error. This is the code that I think have something to do with it
upload_widget.dart

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import '../services/auth_service.dart';
import '../services/storage_service.dart';
import '../theme/theme.dart';

class UploadPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const UploadPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UploadPage> createState() => _UploadPageState();
}

class _UploadPageState extends State<UploadPage> {
  late final TextEditingController? titleControl,
      descriptionControl,
      amount,
      dateControl;
  final ImagePicker _picker = ImagePicker();
  final FocusNode title = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode description = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode date = FocusNode();
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  File? _image;
  late String url;
  var uuid = 'Uuid';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }
```

This is the code that I think related to titleControl.
This is the repository that I copy the code from : https://github.com/gdsc-tknp/thriftify/blob/main/lib/widgets/upload_widget.dart
The file of the error that I clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialize all the TextEditingControllers before you try to use them. This can be done in the init block :

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    titleControl = TextEditingController();
...
  }
```

and don't forget to dispose them :

```
@override
  void dispose() {
    titleControl.dispose();
...
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The late modifier is the culprit.
TextEditingControllers (titleControl,descriptionControl, amount, dateControl) should be initialized in the initState method.

Eg.

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    titleControl = TextEditingController(); // descriptionControl, amount, dateControl as well
    super.initState();
  }
```